# Beginner Question PHP (ServerQuestion)

Tags: php, debian

Hy!!

I just get a vserver running debian. I just installed apache and php. Now the server should support php.

i uploaded the file index.php:

```
<?

echo "Hallo";

?>
```

The problem is if i start a request to the site my browser wants to download a file.

Whats could be the problem?

THX

Comment: Note that closing PHP tags can be omitted, in fact it's recommended not to use them if your whole file is between `<? ... ?>`

Comment: Voted to move to serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you restarted apache after installing PHP?

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: it was my fault- i just restarted the server. THX

Answer (score 2):

This could mean that the Mime extension of the File is not registered with the web server which means you will need to check if you have the PHP Interpreter installed as a extension/plugin in your server.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
    echo "Hallo";
```

The **short_open_tags** is disabled in may distributions by default. If you have to support legacy pages you can anable them in *php.ini*, if not then just use the above, your code will be more compatible.

Comment: If it was only the short tags then wouldn't the page still display, but render the tags and php code as plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Your server isn't set to parse PHP files before they are output.

Check out these pages:
http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-7100332.html
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/516.cfm

Answer (score 1):

If your page works if you changed that to the `<?php` tags, then vbence would be right, it could be as shanethehat says that you just need to restart apache if you've already made the change to php.ini, one of the joys of all these things working together you need to work through all the options to find out where these things fall down so you know where to start looking to fix it

(Found why it wasnt displaying, I hadnt put code round the php tags)

Comment: Huh? this isnt what I submitted at the time, there was way more than this.. Sigh